# QgsMapCanvas.setExtent() has no effect when loading and rendering many layers

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, extents, rendering

The following script is intended to load a pile of vector layers (50 times the same) and after loading to set map canvas center and scale:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer, QgsDataSourceUri, QgsPointXY
from qgis.utils import iface

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
center = QgsPointXY(4428590, 5495530)
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
current_group = root.addGroup('Test Group')

layers = 50 * ['routing_network']

u = QgsDataSourceUri()
u.setSrid('31468')
u.setDatabase('c:/tmp/routing_slow.sqlite')
u.setKeyColumn('ogc_fid')
for lyr in layers:
    u.setDataSource('', lyr, 'geometry')
    l = QgsVectorLayer(u.uri(), 'test layer', 'spatialite')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(l, False)
    current_group.addLayer(l)

canvas.setCenter(center)
canvas.zoomScale(2000)
print('new extent set')
```

When the `for` loop has run through, the scripts prints out `new extent set` immediatly, but leaves map canvas extent to the full extent of the layers:

[image]

This is how it should look, when setting things on the console after rendering is completed:

[image]

Since rendering the layers takes some (~10) seconds, can it be that the canvas extent is set to the layers extent *after* rendering overriding the `setCenter()` and `zoomScale()` at the very end of the script?

Weird observation: when doing a `iface.mapCanvas().zoomScale(50000)` (scale in full extent is 1:192000) *during rendering* rendering continues at scale 1:50.000.

How to deal with this? Is there a way of setting map canvas extent only when rendering is complete?

Comment: try using his signal `QgsMapCanvas::renderComplete ( QPainter *   ) 
`https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#a4bdb701f5f08067ff4ce00de9e19b662